# Visual Studio 2010 foundation server - do I need a domain controller

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

As a solo developer, I don't really *need* team foundation server, but I own a copy so I wanted to try it out and see if I like it better for source control.

I have small network of windows severs (most 2008), but don't use a domain controller as most machines run in isolation and the number of users are very small (max 5 people).

I installed team foundation server just fine on a windows 2008 server (running in a VMware VM) that also has my development database (SQL 2008 R2)...the install worked with no errors, but I cannot seem to give myself permissions to do anything from within visual studio 2010...I can see and connect to the VSTS server, but every operation (add to source control, create project etc) fails due to lack of permissions.

I am wondering now, does VSTS requires a primary domain controller in order to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No domain controller. You first need to setup permissions for your account on the server in Team Foundation Management console.

HTH!
Thomas